# GM 6l90 transmission swap

Tags: transmission, gm, swap

I have a 2012 Chevy Express van 2500 with a 4.8l motor and 6l90 transmission with 200k miles. I bought a used 6l90 with 77k miles from a junk yard, that came out of an identically van. Same year, 2500, same motor, same transmission, etc. Should I need/have to reflash the tcm for it to work correctly after install?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If they came out of the same van model of the same year, I wouldn't think so. I cannot tell you for sure, though. I just wouldn't expect the need as such.

Comment: Hi Paulster2, thank you for the welcome. And thank you for the reply. The new(used) tranny is out of the exact same van. Length, door configuration, base model, etc. No difference other than they are two separate vehicles.

Comment: I would bet physically they are identical. To me there should be no worries, but if there does turn out to be such, you'd need to get it flashed anyway. My suggestion is to put it in and give it a rip. You're in no worse shape than you're in now and I'll give even odds you'll not have any issues.

Comment: You're probably going to have to write the VIN to the TCM and definitely do an adapt relearn. If you're feeling adventerous you could swap the valve body.